# Undeploy a webapp on Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, war, undeploy

When I click on undeploy in the Tomcat manager it sometimes does not remove the webapp. It says

> OK - Undeployed application at context path /myApp

but the application is still listed up.

So I tried to delete it directly from the filesystem. But after reloading Tomcat the web application appears again.

Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I tried to delete it directly from the filesystem. But after reloading tomcat the webapplication appears again.

If you had both the .war and the unpacked directory, make sure that you delete both.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the application folder from the @TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina directory.